# Removing all numbers and letters after a specific character

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently working on a table where I have the sale price in the wrong format in some places please see [my google sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V0T8doTMQiLrLE9LKPpRy467cIhRTiDcvzn6te5BGvg/edit?usp=sharing)

Essentially, I have something like this:

```
Price
22.99;&amp
19.99:sales
22.99
16.99
16.99;---11
18.99;:=---21
30.99
17.99
27.99
28.99
19.99
23.99
59.99
49.99aaa
```

I want to remove all the unneccessary characters after the `:` or `;` or even letters.

I tried using this function `=LEFT(E2,FIND(";",E2)-1)` and whilst it initially worked for some, I ended up getting this instead:

```
Repaired Price
22.99
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
16.99
18.99
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
```

Not sure where I messed up now. I am sure there maybe another easier way or a fix for this

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cell G2 I entered this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(E2:E15&"", "(\d+\.\d+)")+0)
```

See if that works for you?

---

### Explanation

- [See here](https://regex101.com/r/FvPVCd/1) for an explanation of the regex pattern.

---

### References

- [Regexextract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [Arrayformula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! Thanks! Where did I go wrong just out of interest? Also, please if you could be kind sir can you explain what you formula does in some detail as I am new to google sheets. I don't understand the regexextract bit

Comment: Added a link to an explanation of the regex. The error you received with your formula is caused by the FIND() function. In the cells with an error there is no semi-colon present. Therefore, the FIND() returns an error.

Comment: thanks mate, what does this bit do `regexextract(E2:E15&""`?

Comment: The &"" basically forces the values to a text format (string). Most of the values are clearly string but values like 30.99 are (most likely) formatted as numbers. Regexextract (as well as LEFT and FIND) require text (strings) to function. So, removing &"" would result in errors for the cells that have numeric values. The +0 add the end then formats the output (back) to a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining this! I just accepted the answer